# Como implementar axios en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy haciendo mi pagina de autenticacion (Login) y primero habia realizado las request de los datos de usuario con un API propio y fetch (que es como lo pueden visualizar en el codigo), pero quiero cambiarlo a axios y estoy un poco atorado, para poder hacer el request a la siguiente direccion:

> https://reqres.in/

La cual es el API de donde obtendre el usuario y el id de usuario.

Este es mi codigo:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Button, Dialog, Typography} from '@material-ui/core';
import { Email, Lock } from '@material-ui/icons';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import bio from '../../assets/react.jpeg';
import axios from "axios";

let authToken ='';

class Login extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            badLogin: '',
            dialogOpen:false,
            forgottenPwdEmail:'',
            checkEmail: '',
            emailClicked:{backgroundColor:'white',color:'black'},
            passwordClicked:{backgroundColor: 'white',color: 'black'}
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]:event.target.value})
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        if(event.currentTarget.className.includes("email")){
            this.setState({emailClicked:{backgroundColor:'blue',color:'white'}});
        } else if(event.currentTarget.className.includes("password")) {
            this.setState({passwordClicked:{backgroundColor:'blue',color:'white'}});
        } else {
            this.setState({dialogOpen:true})
        }
    }

    handleBlur(event) {
        if(event.currentTarget.name === 'email'){
            this.setState({emailClicked:{backgroundColor:'white',color:'black'}});
        } else if (event.currentTarget.name === 'password') {
            this.setState({passwordClicked:{backgroundColor:'white',color:'black'}});
        }
    }

    handleClose(){
        this.setState({dialogOpen:false})
    }

    attemptLogIn(){
        fetch('http://192.168.15.7:8080/login', {
           method: 'post',
           headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
           body: JSON.stringify({"user": {"email":this.state.email,"password":this.state.password}}) 
        })
        .then(response =>{
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }
            return response.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
            this.props.LogIn(data)
            this.props.history.push('/mainview');
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    render() {
        let display_message;
        if (this.state.badLogin){
            display_message = <p style={{marginBottom:0}}>{this.state.badLogin}</p>
        }
        document.body.style = 'background: #FFFFFF';
        return(
            <div align="center" className='centered-elements'>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
                <img className="img-logo" src={bio} alt="biologo" style={{margin:'auto',height:337,width:600}} />
                <Typography><h1 className="titulo-login">¡Bienvenido al Blog de React!</h1></Typography>
                <form onSubmit={(e)=>e.preventDefault()}>
                <table className='form-table' style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr className="login-table-tr tr-first" align="center">
                          <td className="login-table-td login-table-td-icon td-first" style={this.state.emailClicked}><Email style={{fontSize: 40}}></Email></td>
                          <td className="login-table-td login-table-td-input td-second">
                            <TextField type="email" name="email" label="Correo electrónico"
                              className="disable-selection email" variant="outlined"
                              onChange={this.handleChange} onClick={this.handleClick} onBlur={this.handleBlur}/>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr className="login-table-tr tr-second" align="center">
                          <td className="login-table-td login-table-td-icon td-first" style={this.state.passwordClicked}><Lock style={{fontSize: 40}}></Lock></td>
                          <td className="login-table-td login-table-td-input td-second">
                            <TextField type="password" name="password" label="Contraseña"
                              className="disable-selection password" variant="outlined"
                              onChange={this.handleChange} onClick={this.handleClick} onBlur={this.handleBlur}/>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <Typography>
                    <p style={{color: 'black', width:'440px', textAlign:'right', fontSize:"0.8em"}}>
                      <b onClick={this.handleClick} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</b>
                    </p>
                    <p style={{color: '#ef5350'}}>{display_message}</p>
                    <p style={{color: 'black', width:'440px', textAlign:'right', fontSize:"0.8em"}}>
                    ¿Eres nuevo en el Blog de React? <br/>    
                        <Link to={`/signup`}>
                        ¡¡Registrate!!
                        </Link>

                    </p>
                    </Typography>
                    <div style={{width: '440px'}}>
                      <Button align="right" className="login-button" onClick={() => this.attemptLogIn()} type="submit">Iniciar Sesión</Button>
                    </div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                </form>

                <Dialog
                    open={this.state.dialogOpen}
                    onClose={this.handleClose}
                    aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
                >

                    <div style={{width:'500px',height:'320px'}}>
                    <div className="outer" style={{width:'500px',height:'270px'}}>
                        <div className="middle">
                        <div className="inner">
                            <p>    </p>
                            <h2 style={{textAlign: 'center', fontWeight:'500'}}>Recuperar contraseña</h2>
                            <p style={{padding: '0 10% 0 10%'}}>Introduzca la dirección de correo electrónico asociados con su cuenta de Bio-alchemist</p>
                            <input type="email" name="forgottenPwdEmail" className="disable-selection" onChange={this.handleChange} style={{marginLeft: '40px', width:'80%', border:'solid 1px #4c4c4c', borderRadius:'3px'}}></input>
                            <p style={{padding: '0 10% 0 10%', color: '#ac5fd3'}}>{this.state.checkEmail}</p>
                            <div className="holder">
                            <Button id="pop-up-button" className="login-button" onClick={(e) => this.recoverPassword(e)}>Recuperar contraseña</Button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Dialog>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Les agradezco mucho su apoyo, recien comienzo a aprender React!!! Por lo que me van apareciendo dudas, asi que cualquier comentario o respuesta nuevamente, se los agradezco muchisimo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te voy a explicar la manera que yo suelo utilizar.

Hay diferentes maneras de hacerlo, una es llamar a la funcion(`axios`) directamente y la otra es mediante los metodos(get,post y etc...)

Por ejemplo podemos hacer una llamada `post` de la siguiente manera.

```
attemptLogIn() {
    axios.post('http://192.168.15.7:8080/login', JSON.stringify({
        "user": {
          "email": this.state.email,
          "password": this.state.password
        }
    }),
    {headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }}).then(response => {
      //Comprobar si todo va bien
      // if(response.status !== 200) {
      //   throw Error("El estado de la conexion no es 200")
      // }
      return response.data
    }).then(data => {
      //Procesar los datos.
      console.log(data)
    }).catch(err => {     
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```

En cambio, si llamamos directamente la funcion `axios`, el codigo nos quedaría así.

```
attemptLogIn() {
    axios({
      url:'http://192.168.15.7:8080/login',
      method:'post', //Fijate que aqui le tenemos que decir el metodo.
      data: JSON.stringify(payload), //Objeto a enviar
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(response => {
      //Comprobar si todo va bien
      return response.data
    }).then(data => {
      //Procesar los datos.
      console.log(data)
    }).catch(err => {     
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Otra posibilidad que tenemos es llamar la función con una configuración general.

Por ejemplo, imagínate que todos tus peticiones van a tener la cabecera `Content-Type`

Para eso podemos crear un método que nos crea una instancia y nos la devuelva ya una configuración general.

Imagínate que tenemos un archivo llamado request.js y tenemos este código.

```
const request = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://192.168.15.7:8080', //url base de tu api.
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} //Añadimos las cabeceras.
});

//Exportamos nuestra instancia, para asi poder utilizarlo en cualquier otro archivo
export default request
```

Despues nosotros podemos importar esta función en otro archivo y utilizarlo.

```
import request from './request.js' //Archivo creado anteriormente
//Ahora no hace falta pasar los headers, porque la instancia(request) ya los tiene
request.post('http://192.168.15.7:8080/login', payload)
```

Hay muchas posibilidades de utilizar axios y cada uno elige la que más se le ajusta.

En cualquier caso te dejo [aqui](https://github.com/axios/axios) la documentación oficial.

Espero haberte ayudado. Cualquier duda estaré encantado de ayudarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio de mucho!!!

Comment: Me surgio una nueva duda, puedo llamar dos web de API diferentes en un mismo componente? Es decir, hacer dos bloques de codigo con axios para usar los dos APIs, para datos diferentes que encuentro en una pagina, pero no en la otra

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a la ayuda de Eugeni Bejan pude implementar axios en lugar de fetch, les dejo mi codigo corregido y funcional, por si es de utilidad a alguien:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Button, Dialog, Typography} from '@material-ui/core';
import { Email, Lock } from '@material-ui/icons';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import bio from '../../assets/react.jpeg';
import axios from "axios";

let authToken ='';

class Login extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            badLogin: '',
            dialogOpen:false,
            dialogPass:false,
            forgottenPwdEmail:'',
            checkEmail: '',
            emailClicked:{backgroundColor:'white',color:'black'},
            passwordClicked:{backgroundColor: 'white',color: 'black'}
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]:event.target.value})
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        if(event.currentTarget.className.includes("email")){
            this.setState({emailClicked:{backgroundColor:'blue',color:'white'}});
        } else if(event.currentTarget.className.includes("password")) {
            this.setState({passwordClicked:{backgroundColor:'blue',color:'white'}});
        } else {
            this.setState({dialogOpen:true})
        }
    }

    handleBlur(event) {
        if(event.currentTarget.name === 'email'){
            this.setState({emailClicked:{backgroundColor:'white',color:'black'}});
        } else if (event.currentTarget.name === 'password') {
            this.setState({passwordClicked:{backgroundColor:'white',color:'black'}});
        }
    }

    handleClose(){
        this.setState({dialogOpen:false})
        this.setState({dialogPass:false})
    }

    attemptLogIn(){
        axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://reqres.in/api/'
        axios.post('login', JSON.stringify({"email":this.state.email,"password":this.state.password}),
        {headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}})
        .then(response =>{
            console.log(response)
            return response.data
        })
        .then(data => {
            this.props.LogIn(data)
            this.props.history.push('/mainview');
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.setState({dialogPass:true})
        });
    }

    render() {
        let display_message;
        if (this.state.badLogin){
            display_message = <p style={{marginBottom:0}}>{this.state.badLogin}</p>
        }
        document.body.style = 'background: #FFFFFF';
        return(
            <div align="center" className='centered-elements'>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
                <img className="img-logo" src={bio} alt="biologo" style={{margin:'auto',height:337,width:600}} />
                <Typography><h1 className="titulo-login">¡Bienvenido al Blog de React!</h1></Typography>
                <form onSubmit={(e)=>e.preventDefault()}>
                <table className='form-table' style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr className="login-table-tr tr-first" align="center">
                          <td className="login-table-td login-table-td-icon td-first" style={this.state.emailClicked}><Email style={{fontSize: 40}}></Email></td>
                          <td className="login-table-td login-table-td-input td-second">
                            <TextField type="email" name="email" label="Correo electrónico"
                              className="disable-selection email" variant="outlined"
                              onChange={this.handleChange} onClick={this.handleClick} onBlur={this.handleBlur}/>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr className="login-table-tr tr-second" align="center">
                          <td className="login-table-td login-table-td-icon td-first" style={this.state.passwordClicked}><Lock style={{fontSize: 40}}></Lock></td>
                          <td className="login-table-td login-table-td-input td-second">
                            <TextField type="password" name="password" label="Contraseña"
                              className="disable-selection password" variant="outlined"
                              onChange={this.handleChange} onClick={this.handleClick} onBlur={this.handleBlur}/>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <Typography>
                    <p style={{color: 'black', width:'440px', textAlign:'right', fontSize:"0.8em"}}>
                      <b onClick={this.handleClick} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</b>
                    </p>
                    <p style={{color: '#ef5350'}}>{display_message}</p>
                    <p style={{color: 'black', width:'440px', textAlign:'right', fontSize:"0.8em"}}>
                    ¿Eres nuevo en el Blog de React? <br/>    
                        <Link to={`/signup`}>
                        ¡¡Registrate!!
                        </Link>

                    </p>
                    </Typography>
                    <div style={{width: '440px'}}>
                      <Button align="right" className="login-button" onClick={() => this.attemptLogIn()} type="submit">Iniciar Sesión</Button>
                    </div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                </form>

                <Dialog
                    open={this.state.dialogOpen}
                    onClose={this.handleClose}
                    aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
                >

                    <div style={{width:'500px',height:'320px'}}>
                    <div className="outer" style={{width:'500px',height:'270px'}}>
                        <div className="middle">
                        <div className="inner">
                            <p>    </p>
                            <h2 style={{textAlign: 'center', fontWeight:'500'}}>Recuperar contraseña</h2>
                            <p style={{padding: '0 10% 0 10%'}}>Introduzca la dirección de correo electrónico asociados con su cuenta de Bio-alchemist</p>
                            <input type="email" name="forgottenPwdEmail" className="disable-selection" onChange={this.handleChange} style={{marginLeft: '40px', width:'80%', border:'solid 1px #4c4c4c', borderRadius:'3px'}}></input>
                            <p style={{padding: '0 10% 0 10%', color: '#ac5fd3'}}>{this.state.checkEmail}</p>
                            <div className="holder">
                            <Button id="pop-up-button" className="login-button" onClick={(e) => this.recoverPassword(e)}>Recuperar contraseña</Button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Dialog>

                <Dialog
                    open={this.state.dialogPass}
                    onClose={this.handleClose}
                    aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
                >

                    <div style={{width:'500px',height:'170px'}}>
                    <div className="outer" style={{width:'500px',height:'120px'}}>
                        <div className="middle">
                        <div className="inner">
                            <p>    </p>
                            <Typography><h2 style={{textAlign: 'center', fontWeight:'500'}}>Error, tus datos son incorrectos</h2>
                            <p style={{padding: '0 10% 0 10%'}}>Favor de introducir una direccion de correo electronico y un password validos</p></Typography>
                            <div className="holder" align="center" >
                            <Button id="pop-up-button" className="login-button" onClick={this.handleClose}>Cerrar</Button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Dialog>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Muchas gracias por su apoyo, espero que esta pequena contribucion sea de utilidad